# Uploaded my website and my images are not showing

Tags: html, css

Source code for every image is `<img src="img/image1.jpg">`

I have a lot of images just kept it simple with `image1` `image2` `image3`...

but I also have subpages that have folders with images that don't work. I also did a responsive page that works on the computer when I shrink the window but not on the phone.

Comment: Share link of your site

Comment: Provide sample code please, use codepen.io for example.

Comment: <img src="img/image1.jpg>

Comment: missed the other " on copy

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Not sure what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Update your image URLs.

For example:

www.mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg

You are probably still linking to your local images folder.

Comment: What's your website URL Clint? I'll let you know how to format your image URLs.

Comment: does it matter if its repeat image names but different folders

Comment: Great! I see you got your background image working. I suggest keeping all of your images in one folder, and reusing the same image so you're not bloating your load time by loading two of the same image.

Comment: well it's not same image but same name but in different folder

Comment: they are different images in different folders but same name. I also don't know why one image from same folder works on my about page

Comment: Personally, I would rename the images differently and keep them in the same folder for organizational consistency. (ie: img/background1.jpg, img/background2.jpg)

Comment: sounds like a plan. do you know why one image works and the rest don't other then the background ones.

Comment: Is this where your images are located: http://www.maverikknives.com/img/image8.png

If yes, is your file name correct, including the extension? (.JPG vs .PNG). I can see in the inspector "404 not found" which means your image is either not uploaded, doesn't exist in the folder, or is named incorrectly. Based on the inspector, I see only two images uploaded to your "img" folder on your server. Upload the rest and this should work for you.

Comment: than you very much that all worked. is there any way you could look at my site for mobile and tell me why my background image is not working right